# Getting variable from inside while loop

Tags: bash, variables, pipe

I have a scritp that gathers information about a subdirectory of files.  I am checking that the time between file creation is uniform.

```
last=0
LOGCHECK="YES"
ls -l /dir/*.log | gawk '{print $8}' | sed s/:/*60+/g | bc |
        while read fname
        do
            current=$fname
            if [ $last = 0 ]; then
                last=$current
            elif [ $((current - last)) -ne 1 ]; then
                echo "Time difference discrepancy: $((current - last)) minute(s) is not expected"
                LOGCHECK="NO"
                last=$current    
            else
                last=$current
            fi      
        done
```

This outputs only if the time between .log file creation is not one minute.  My problem is that the $LOGCHECK inside the while loop is in another subshell I believe from the pipe?

Is there a way to get this variable information?

Answer (score 3):

This is a common situation with `bash` scripting. Restructure your loop like this:

```
while read fname
do
  # stuff
done < <(ls -l /dir/*.log | gawk '{print $8}' | sed s/:/*60+/g | bc)
```

Then variables set within the loop will still be available afterwards.